# Loadrunner measure Siebel rendering UI

Tags: performance, user-interface, loadrunner, siebel

Is there a way to generate a LoadRunner script that also measures the rendering Siebel UI?

I'm using Siebel Open UI 8.1, LR 12 and IE11, Chrome 39 and Firefox 24 browsers.

If it's not to execute this performance scenario with LoadRunner, is there another option to cover it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, GUI Virtual user

GUI VUSER Login Time - Siebel Web Virtual user Login time = Time in GUI for Login

Continue this for any named timed event (save, page, etc...)   This is a well established prototocol dating back as far as 1994.

Time in GUI consists of time required to run JavaScript and time required to draw information on the screen (rendering.)  Check the developer tools of your browser to measure time in JavaScript and time in rendering

FYI: GUI Virtual Users are QTP-based clients.   You could also achieve substantial similarity, without the actual drawing on the screen, but including JavaScript, with Truclient.   But, since you indicate rendering is what you are after, then it goes to GUI virtual user